# cocos2d iPad crash when setting [_director displayStats:NO]

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I just completed a quick 1st draft prototype of a cocos2d iPad app. I have not modified the `CCTextureAtlas.m` file.

The app runs fine when I leave `[director_ setDisplayStats:YES]` in the `AppDelegate`, but if I remove that line or substitute `[director_setDisplayStats:NO]`, it crashes in `CCTextureAtlas.m`.

`-(void) drawNumberOfQuads: (NSUInteger) n fromIndex: (NSUInteger) start` on line 522, which reads:

`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (GLvoid*) (start*6*sizeof(_indices[0])) );`

For reference, `[director_ setDisplayStats:YES]` is on line 154 of `AppDelegate.m`.

The entire sourcecode for the app prototype is located here:

**https://github.com/GameAid/Toddler-Taxonomist**

For a little bit of context for those who might look at the code, after tapping Start, `BoardLayer` is the primary node that coordinates most of the work and what shows on the screen.

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm doing that is causing this to be a problem. At first, I suspected that my use of `[[CCTextureCache sharedCache] removeUnusedTextures]` (in 'BoardLayer') was a problem, but now I think that it doesn't make a difference.

This is the call stack that appears in Xcode:

[image]

Any ideas about how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i would be careful before setting cleanup to NO (leaks lurk big time if you are not careful). I was able to run your app without FPS when (in ccConfig.h) i change

```
#define CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE 1
```

to

```
#define CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE 0
```

per your above answer, there seems to exist a nasty coupling here at the GL level. I dont think that this optimization (state cache) would impact very noticeably (if at all) the perceived performance of your type of app.

ps: nice graphics, will probably become a favourite for many 7-77 yr old kids.

Comment: Heh, thanks! The longer you play it, the more difficult the questions become. :) I'll probably always have a github version of it available for free when I'm done, as I'm trying to get GameAid up and running. I'll take a look at your suggestion. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

In `BoardLayer.m`, I was using `[self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES]`, which seemed to be causing the problem. When I changed it to simply `[self removeAllChildren]`, everything works as expected when `[director_ setShowStats:NO]` is in place.

I'm not sure what the nature of this conflict is -- it appears to be at a low OpenGL level -- but it's fixed in my code.